# How to integrate Company Website with intranet portal?

Tags: asp.net, integration

we have our company intra net portal designed in Asp.net 2.0/sql server 2000 , now we want to deploy this portal to internet so that employees can acesss it from web also so my question is  what is the best way of integrating hosted asp.net site with intra net web site.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to implement is called an [Extranet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extranet):

> An extranet is a private network that
>   uses Internet protocols, network
>   connectivity, and possibly the public
>   telecommunication system to securely
>   share part of an organization's
>   information or operations with
>   suppliers, vendors, partners,
>   customers or other businesses.

Answer (score 0):

If the intranet portal contains sensitive information then I would encrypt it using SSL and the publish it on the web, we have done this with may of our intranet site, e.g. time registration system and TFS. If you want only certain users have access that site, you could configure certificates and then let these users install the certificate on their machines.

Comment: basically it is HR portal that offers HR services to employee but it is accessible within companies intra net ,but company wants to give thier employees access from web ,companies had many sales rep which our  working on remote areas so they will accesses it from internet.

Comment: ok, I see. You could go into code and write some simple web page to display only the HR information the external users will see, in case if you only want to display a subset of you data.